# How to derive a 2d jinc highpass filter from a lowpass filter?

Tags: filters, filter-design

The following code define a jinc lowpass filter, how to derive a corresponding highpass filter? Is it possible?

```
def design_lowpass_filter(numtaps, cutoff, width, fs):
    # Radially symmetric jinc-based filter.
    x = (np.arange(numtaps) - (numtaps - 1) / 2) / fs
    r = np.hypot(*np.meshgrid(x, x))
    f = scipy.special.j1(2 * cutoff * (np.pi * r)) / (np.pi * r)
    beta = scipy.signal.kaiser_beta(scipy.signal.kaiser_atten(numtaps, width / (fs / 2)))
    w = np.kaiser(numtaps, beta)
    f *= np.outer(w, w)
    f /= np.sum(f)
    return f
```

Comment: Have you tried using `h[M]=1-wp`?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I am not sure whether it is correct or not